# Capturing output of nested stored procedure in C#

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I am calling one stored procedure (2) from within another stored procedure (1). Both stored procedures return a dataset in the form of a `SELECT` statement at the end. I need to capture both of these in my c# code, however, my code is only capturing the `Select` dataset of stored procedure (2). Please guide how can I accomplish this?

Here is the format of the procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GoalStop
    @ID INT,
    @StopDate [DATETIME] = NULL
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Return varchar(500);
    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE dbo.Table2
        SET StopDate = @StopDate 
        WHERE TableID = @ID

        SET @Return = 'The Goal was successfully stopped.';

        SELECT 'DATABASE MESSAGE: ' + @Return
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK

        DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(4000), @ErrSeverity INT

        SELECT 
            @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

And the calling stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Goal_Restart]
    @ID [INT],
    @Goal [DECIMAL](18, 8) = NULL,
    @StartDate [DATETIME] = NULL,
    @StopDate [DATETIME] = NULL,
    @Updatedby [VARCHAR](8),
    @UpdateDate [DATETIME] = NULL
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Return varchar(500)

    BEGIN TRY

    SELECT  @Name = Name 
    FROM [dbo].Table1
    WHERE ID = @ID

    --bunch of IF ELSE Statements...

        BEGIN
            EXEC dbo.GoalStop  @ID, @StopDate --Call to other stored procedure
            INSERT INTO [dbo].Table1([Name], [Goal], [StartDate], [StopDate], [Updatedby], [UpdateDate])
            VALUES (@Name, @Goal, @StartDate, @StopDate, @Updatedby, @UpdateDate)

            SET @Return = 'The Goal was successfully created.';             
         END
     END

     SELECT 'DATABASE MESSAGE: ' + @Return

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK

        DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(4000), @ErrSeverity INT
        SELECT @ErrMsg  =  ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
END
```

[image: Output of stored procedure in query analyzer]

and the C# code calling this procedure:

```
string returnString = string.Empty;
SqlDataReader reader;

try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetSqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.Goal_Restart", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandTimeout = 90;

            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Goal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = goal;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Updatedby", SqlDbType.Char, 7).Value = Updatedby;
            command.Parameters.Add("@UpdateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = updateDate;

            if (startDate != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
            }

            if (stopDate != null && (Convert.ToDateTime(stopDate)).ToShortDateString() != "1/1/1900")
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@StopDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = stopDate;
            }

            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            command.Prepare();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                returnString = reader[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I exec in query analyzer, output is the result of two diff queries (Please see image attached)

```
DATABASE MESSAGE: The Goal was successfully Stopped.
DATABASE MESSAGE: The Goal was successfully created.
```

However the `returnString` in C# is capturing only message from the nested procedure and not calling procedure.

```
DATABASE MESSAGE: The Goal was successfully Stopped.
```

How can I capture both or only calling procedure?

Comment: Since you want only one specific value maybe using an output parameter would be a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as your cursor to the next row using `SqlDataReaderReader.Read`, you must also cursor to the next ***resultset*** using [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Do something with first resultset
}
var ok = reader.NextResult();
if (ok)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Do something with outer proc's resultset  
    }
}
```